# $.post submitting form before inner Ajax can run

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm not sure if its the best practice to do this but I've got an $.post with an Ajax inside. The issue is if I remove the return false from the $.post then the form will submit before Ajax can run.

```
$(".buy").submit(function(e) {

  var url = "http://perfectprints.org.uk/Canvas/js/send_email.php";

  html2canvas($('.canvas-cut')).then(function(canvas) {

    $('canvas').addClass('canvas-layout');
    var src = canvas.toDataURL();
    var output = src.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    $.post('image.php', {
      data: output
    }).done(function(response) {
      alert("Done");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
          shape: shape,
          finish: finish,
          ori: ori,
          current_width: current_width,
          current_height: current_height
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
        }
      });
    });

  });
  return false;
});
```

This will only work if return false is in place to stop $.post from firing.
I've attempted to try to submit the form after ajax has finished but it wouldn't work.

Any help or advice would be most welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to decide which you want to do, post the form or submit via AJAX. If you need to use AJAX for some sort of processing before the form is submitted, then change the submit button to a normal button, and then do the AJAX call, and submit the form when the AJAX returns success.

Comment: Depending what you want to accomplish, you need some combination of `form.submit()` and/or `event.preventDefault()`. You can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop submission, which also automatically fires when you `return false;`, but unlike `return false;`, does not break the function. Then use `form.submit()` with whatever conditional logic is needed to control submission manually.

Comment: More on this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with PHP, because this is only in the scope of frontend javascript.

Comment: Please explain the behavior you expect. Really not clear what the problem is

Comment: @charlietfl I need both the $.post ajax to function, at the moment only the $.post will function.                                                                               Thank you, I'll make some changes with all of your advice.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense...what else is not working?

Comment: When the a user submits the form, the $.post runs, executing its contents. However if "return false" is not on $.post then Ajax doesn't have a chance to run. I hope that makes better sense.

Comment: Does that mean you want the whole form to submit also after the ajax completes? You currently have an animation in the success handler so it was assumed you don't want form to submit based on that

Comment: @Loki180, I need you to share your HTML as well and trust me it's worth the try

Comment: @user10089632 what is relevance of the html? It is clear that it is a form

Comment: @charlietfl, His script is very likely not executing at all due to mark up syntax error

Comment: @user10089632 that makes no sense based on all the comments and problem description in question

Comment: A form is being submitted, its a PayPal Button. As far as I can tell, $.post is submitting the form before Ajax, within $.post, has a chance to trigger.I thought just returning false on $.post and then calling the form to post inside the success of Ajax but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a button with type button and id.
This element not submit the form data by default and could be used to make Ajax calls.

```
<button id="button_buy" type="button">Buy</button>
```

Then add a event click to this button and use the actual code of submit event.

```
$("#button_buy").click(function(e) {
    //code of $(".buy").submit

    //inside ajax success fire submit event's form
    //$('the_form).submit();

    //delete return false
});
```

Comment: I'll give this ago Jorge, THank you for taking the time to help me out.

Comment: Did it, I added a button to the form and re-wrote some of $.post and Ajax with a submit() on success. Thank you all for the help.